# $http:GET Invalid basic header. No credentials provided

Tags: angularjs, http

When i tried to access star wars API using $http method . am getting 403 response with message "**Invalid basic header. No credentials provided**" what am missing here?

```
$http({
  method : 'GET',
  url : 'https://swapi.co/api/people/'
}).then(function(success) {

  var data = JSON.parse(body);
  var result = data.result.filter(function each(r) {
    return username == r.name && password == r.birth_year;
  });


}, function(error) {
  alert('not logged::' + eror)

});
```

Could you please someone help me to find the issue?

Comment: Are you working in Angular 1 or 2+ project?

Comment: am working in angular 1 project.

Comment: Works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/j6x6zivWmmIV7Y9iOZAj?p=preview. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, as I just did. Note that your callback makes no sense: you're never using the response you get back from the API.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrongly the data returned by the get call.
You don't need to parse it to JSON, it's already a JSON.

Here's a plunker with a call to the API working. Hope it helps you
https://plnkr.co/edit/WKQfqc7wxmBJIjYUyZKe

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myAppController', function($http, $scope) {

$scope.callApi = function() {
  $http.get('https://swapi.co/api/people/').then(function(result) {

    $scope.characters = result.data.results;

  }, function(error) {
    alert('not logged::' + error)
  });
}
});
```